# Conflict Between MSODBC and SQL Anywhere Drivers in Dockerized Debian

Tags: sql-server, docker, sqlanywhere

I am running a Django application in a Docker container based on Debian. My application needs to connect to both Microsoft SQL Server and SQL Anywhere databases, so I'm trying to use the Microsoft ODBC Driver (msodbcsql17) for SQL Server and the SQL Anywhere 17 driver. However, I'm encountering a frustrating issue: when the MSODBC driver is configured and working correctly, the SQL Anywhere driver stops working, and vice versa. I can't seem to have them both operational at the same time.

**Environment:**

- Host OS: Windows
- Docker Version: latest
- Debian Image Version: python:3.10-bullseye
- MSODBC Driver Version: 17
- SQL Anywhere Driver Version: 17

**Steps Taken:**

1. Installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server using official Debian packages or Microsoft's script.
2. Installed SQL Anywhere driver using official packages and set up.
3. Configured `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include paths to both drivers.
4. Give full permisions to hole package

**Symptoms:**

- When MSODBC is operational (confirmed by [describe successful connection to SQL Server), attempting to connect to SQL Anywhere results in .
- Conversely, when SQL Anywhere is operational, attempting to connect to SQL Server via MSODBC results in "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)".

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone faced a similar issue with these drivers in a Dockerized Debian environment?
2. Are there known conflicts between these drivers that I should be aware of?
3. Can you suggest any configurations or diagnostic steps to help isolate and resolve this conflict?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
# Use Debian Bullseye as the base image
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
# Environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# System dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libsasl2-dev \
    build-essential \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    liblcms2-dev \
    libopenjp2-7-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    tk-dev \
    tcl-dev \
    tini \
    chromium \
    chromium-driver \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev
ARG PLATFORM
ENV PLATFORM=$PLATFORM
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV ISDOCKER=True
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/
#
# Register the Microsoft Debian repository and import its GPG public key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

# Set environment variables for the driver
#
# install SQL anywhere 17
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://d5d4ifzqzkhwt.cloudfront.net/sqla17client/sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xavf sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    cd client17011 && \
    ./setup -nogui -I_accept_the_license_agreement -silent

## create a driver template
RUN echo "[SQL Anywhere 17]" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Description=SAP SQL Anywhere 17 ODBC Driver" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Driver=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17_r.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Setup=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17_r.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "UsageCount=1" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
#

# Application setup
RUN chmod +x "/code/start_api.sh" \
    && chmod +x "/code/start_worker.sh" \
    && chmod +x "/code/start_notificator.sh"

# SQL Anywhere paths
ENV SQLANY17="/opt/sqlanywhere17"
ENV SQLANYSAMP17="/opt/sqlanywhere17/samples"
ENV PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$SQLANY17/bin64:$SQLANY17/bin32:${PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python -m pip install pipenv \
    && pipenv install --dev --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile
```

this works for sql anywhere

```
# Use Debian Bullseye as the base image
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
# Environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# System dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libsasl2-dev \
    build-essential \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    liblcms2-dev \
    libopenjp2-7-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    tk-dev \
    tcl-dev \
    tini \
    chromium \
    chromium-driver \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev
ARG PLATFORM
ENV PLATFORM=$PLATFORM
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV ISDOCKER=True
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/
#
# Register the Microsoft Debian repository and import its GPG public key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

# Set environment variables for the driver
#
# install SQL anywhere 17
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://d5d4ifzqzkhwt.cloudfront.net/sqla17client/sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xavf sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    cd client17011 && \
    ./setup -nogui -I_accept_the_license_agreement -silent

## create a driver template
RUN echo "[SQL Anywhere 17]" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Description=SAP SQL Anywhere 17 ODBC Driver" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Driver=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17_r.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Setup=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17_r.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "UsageCount=1" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
#

# Application setup
RUN chmod +x "/code/start_api.sh" \
    && chmod +x "/code/start_worker.sh" \
    && chmod +x "/code/start_notificator.sh"

# SQL Anywhere paths
ENV SQLANY17="/opt/sqlanywhere17"
ENV SQLANYSAMP17="/opt/sqlanywhere17/samples"
ENV PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$SQLANY17/bin64:$SQLANY17/bin32:${PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib32:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python -m pip install pipenv \
    && pipenv install --dev --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile
```

this works for mssql

````
ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc3504d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f00e1760000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f00e1756000)
        libodbcinst.so.2 => /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f00e14ba000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f00e13e0000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f00e138d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f00e11be000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f00e107a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f00e1060000)```
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f00e103e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f00e0e6a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f00e1b82000)
        libdbtasks17_r.so => /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbtasks17_r.so (0x00007f00e0c20000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f00e0c04000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f00e0bd4000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f00e0bce000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f00e0bbf000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f00e0bb8000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f00e0b9e000)
````

Comment: Aside... if you `docker run -it --rm python:3.10-bullseye cat /etc/os-release` you'll see that the image is based on Debian 11, not Debian 10 as in your Microsoft package reference URLs.

Comment: Aside... `apt-key` has been deprecated since Debian 9 days. Its continued use can lead to failed installations due to improper signature handling.

Comment: I'll add another aside: The current SQL Server ODBC version is 18, not 17. Without saving the two Dockerfiles and doing a diff it's hard to tell if there's *any* difference between them.

Comment: You should probably follow the [SQL Server ODBC installation script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=debian18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#18) *and* do a diff of the two Dockerfiles to see what's different.

Comment: You should probably try to find the official instructions for the SQL Anywhere ODBC driver. That's too much code and manual tweaking. [Tweaking PATH or manually writing to odbcinst.ini isn't recommended](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/01/sap-sql-anywhere-tips-odbc-setting-on-linux/).

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the output of `ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1` between containers generated from the two Dockerfile build images, you might see something odd like SQL Anywhere stealing references to system libs.

Comment: i tried but got same error